# What is the difference between String.subString() and String.subSequence()

Tags: java, string, substring, subsequence

`String.subSequence()` has the following javadoc:

> Returns a new character sequence that is a subsequence of this
>   sequence.
>
> An invocation of this method of the form
>
> ```
> str.subSequence(begin, end)
> ```
>
> behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation
>
> ```
> str.substring(begin, end)
> ```
>
> This method is defined so that the String class can implement the
>   CharSequence interface.

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Using `str.subSequence(begin, end)` returns a [CharSequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) which is a read-only form of the string represented as a sequence of chars.
For example:

```
String string = "Hello";
CharSequence subSequence = string.subSequence(0, 5);
```

It's read only in the sense that you can't change the `chars` within the `CharSequence` without instantiating a new instance of a `CharSequence`.

If you have to use `str.subSequence(begin, end)`, you can cast the result to a `String`:

```
String string = "Hello";
String subSequence = (String) string.subSequence(0, 5);
```

and use all the normal `String` operators like `subSequence += " World";`

Answer (score 54):

To understand this, the very first thing you need to know is that what is the difference between **substring** and **subsequence**

**substring** is a *continuous* part or subpart  of a string

whereas

**subsequence** is the part of a string or sequence, that might be continuous or not but the *order* of the elements is maintained

For example, let's say we have the following strings:

```
str_a="hello there"
str_b="hello"
str_c="ello th"
str_d="hllo"
str_e="ho hre"
str_f="there hello"
```

`str_b` is a substring of `str_a`, `str_c` is also a substring of `str_a` but `str_d` is not a substring of `str_a` as this substring is not *continuous*.

Now all substrings are subsequences as the order is maintained.

`str_d` is a subsequence of `str_a`, `str_e` is also a subsequence of `str_a` however `str_f` is not a subsequence of `str_a` as in this case the *order* is not maintained.

Now for java, there is no appropriate clarification regarding these methods in javadoc.

Answer (score 50):

**Subsequence**

Subsequence is a generalisation of substring, suffix, and prefix. Finding the longest string which is a subsequence of two or more strings is known as the longest common subsequence problem.

Example: The string "anna" is a subsequence of the string "banana":

```
banana
 || ||
 an na
```

**Substring**

A substring of a string is a prefix of a suffix of the string, and equivalently a suffix of a prefix. If one string is a substring of another, it is also a subsequence, which is a more general concept.

Example: The string "ana" is a substring (and subsequence) of banana at two different offsets:

```
banana
 |||||
 ana||
   |||
   ana
```

Read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring).

But as far as Java is concerned, there isn't any difference in their use as stated clearly in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#subSequence%28int,%20int%29). Also as it's stated in there, the method `subSequence` has only been implemented in class `String` so as to keep it compliant with the `CharSequence` interface.
And this method's name is indeed just a misnomer.

Answer (score 13):

In simple terms of understanding:

**Substring** : A substring is a contiguous sequence of characters within a string, where oder matters.

```
Substring
string
ring
```

**Subsequences**: From a string, any of the character but in sequence.

```
Substring
u s i
s b t i n g
r g
```

Answer (score 2):

Substrings are consecutive subsequences.

For example, for sequence abc we have

```
substrings: a, ab, abc, b, bc, c, and the empty substring;
subsequences: a, b, ab, c, ac, bc, abc, and the empty subsequence.
```

When the letters are repeated, some substrings and subsequences will look the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source of String, you will see that subsequence actually calls substring.  The only thing it does different than substring is it casts the string to a CharSequence.

Answer (score 0):

In short, it doesn't matter much for `String` objects. They are equivalent, unless you need to pass the result to something which only takes `String`, in which case you must use the `subtring(int,int)` version or cast the `subsequence(int,int)` version to a `String` (because that's what it is, internally).

`String.substring(int,int)` existed first, because `String` existed first. In Java 1.4, `CharSequence` was added, and somebody apparently realized that it would be useful to have the same functionality there, but which returned a `CharSequence` instead of `String` (for flexibility). So, along came `CharSequence.subSequence(int,int)`. However, since `String` implements `CharSequence`, `String` inherited the seemingly redundant method.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is off the code; to for understanding.

**Let’s start with what we mean by “sequence” and “subsequence.”**

> Sequence

- A sequence is a list of items in which the order of items matters.
- For example, the string GACA contains the same character (A) multiple times, and it differs from the string CAAG, which has the same population of characters.

> Subsequence

- A subsequence Z of a string X is X, possibly with items removed.
- For example, if X is the string GAC, then it has eight subsequences:

  1: GAC (no characters removed)

  2: GA (C removed),

  3: GC (A removed),

  4: AC (G removed),

  5: G (A and C removed),

  6: A (G and C removed),

  7: C (G and A removed), and

  8: the empty string (all characters removed).
- For example, if X is the string CATCGA and Y is the string GTACCGTCA, then CCA is a common subsequence of X and Y consisting of three characters.

**Note 1:** It is not a **longest common subsequence** (LCS), however, since the common subsequence CTCA has four characters.

**Note 2:** CTCA is a longest common subsequence, but it is not unique, since TCGA is another common subsequence with four characters.

> Substring

- a substring is a subsequence of a string in which the characters must be drawn from contiguous positions in the string.
- For example the string CATCGA, the subsequence ATCG is a substring but the subsequence CTCA is not.

Answer (score -1):

Basically it is just what is returned. One a String and the other a CharSequence (which you can cast as a string).
You would use the subSequence when you need a CharSequence type of variable.