# Difference between subSequence and subString methods in java String class

Tags: java

I have a little confusion regarding the difference between subSequence method and subString method in Java String class. I read the article [What is the difference between String.subString() and String.subSequence()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505508/what-is-the-difference-between-string-substring-and-string-subsequence) which was been answered to this question but I have a little confusion, the article mentioned "**Its read only in the sense that you can't change the chars within the CharSequence without instantiating a new instance of a CharSequence**".

But when I tried with the following example it

```
String string = "Hello";
CharSequence subSequence = string.subSequence(0, 5);
System.out.println(subSequence.subSequence(1, 4));
subSequence = subSequence.subSequence(1, 4);
System.out.println(subSequence);
```

it prints
ell
ell

I do not know whether I have understood it correctly. Can you please help me to clarify this and please tell me the difference between **subString and subSequence** with an example

thanks a lot

Comment: read about immutable

Comment: Should this not be marked as duplicate?

Comment: `I do not know whether I have understood it correctly` What exactly is your understanding? What output would you expect instead?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As explained in the article you linked to, the only difference between those two methods is the return type.  One returns a `String` and the other returns a `CharSequence`.

The thing to understand is that `CharSequence` is an **interface**, and `String` is a **class** which **implements** `CharSequence`.

So every `String` is also a `CharSequence`, but not vice versa.  You can assign the output of `substring()` to a variable of type `CharSequence`, but not the other way around:

```
String string = "Hello";

String subString1 = string.substring(1,4);             // ell
String subString2 = string.subSequence(1, 4);          // Type mismatch compiler error

CharSequence subSequence1 = string.subSequence(1, 4);  // ell
CharSequence subSequence2 = string.substring(1, 4);    // ell
```

In this particular case, since we're executing the `subSequence()` method on a `String` object, the `String` implementation will be invoked, which just returns a `substring()`:

```
public CharSequence subSequence(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
    return this.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
}
```

This is what people are talking about when they say the `substring()` and `subSequence()` methods are identical when you call them on a `String`.

---

Regarding the code you posted, since you started with a `String`, all your calls to `subSequence()` are really just `substring()` calls under the covers.  So each time you try to "change" your `CharSequence`, the compiler is really just creating another `String` object and passing you a reference to the new one, rather than changing the existing object.

Even though your variable is of type `CharSequence`, the object it refers to is really a `String`.

Comment: `subSequence` could even return a `StringBuilder` which is also a `CharSequence`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Actually, the implementation of subSequence() in the StringBuilder and StringBuffer classes also both return a String.  I'm not sure about other implementations, though.

Answer (score 0):

> "Its read only in the sense that you can't change the chars within the CharSequence without instantiating a new instance of a CharSequence".

I believe that part of your confusion is that you think you are changing the chars within the `CharSequence` with the following code:

```
CharSequence subSequence = string.subSequence(0, 5);
subSequence = subSequence.subSequence(1, 4);
```

Note that the second line creates a brand new `CharSequence` object and overwrites the original one. It **does not** change the original `CharSequence`. To understand this better, I suggest you read a little more about reference variables.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Prepare two examples, one using subSequence and one using subString. 
Each will give a result.
Try to modify both results and watch what happens.

A modification is any operation on the string, which would result in a different string, like adding or removing characters, or changing characters.