# What uses are there for String#subSequence()

Tags: java, string, substring, subsequence

So I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26560496/1706924) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15506138/1706924) on the differences between `subSequence()` and `subString()` and I understand that the only difference between the two is the return type. In fact, `subSequence()` calls `subString()` under the hood.

In addition, this [article on subSequence](https://www.journaldev.com/813/java-string-subsequence-example) states at the end that:

> There is **no benefit** in using `subSequence` method, ideally you should
>   always use String `substring` method.

Is there really no benefit to using `subSequence()`? If so, why has it been introduced? If there is a benefit, what is it and what known uses are for it?

Comment: ```subSequence``` is not a ```String``` method, it's a ```CharSequence``` method. If you are dealing with ```String``` you should always use ```substring```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's plenty of APIs where `CharSequences` are used instead of `Strings` - this happens when a `CharSequence` is "good enough" and the authors of the API believe that the elasticity added (e.g. possibility of aggressive optimization by using mutable implementations) overweight the benefit of safety offered by Strings.

A good, notable example is Android - almost all methods defined on widgets (see, for example, the [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView)) that one would reasonably expect to take `String` - like `setText` - take a `CharSequence` instead.

So, of course, when an `TextView` needs to only take a part of the text, it will need to use the `subsequence` method.

Answer (score 4):

There's the benefit of abstraction when that's applicable to a program. As an example:

```
public CharSequence getPrefix(CharSequence cs) {
    return cs.subSequence(0, 1);
}
```

And this can be called any `CharSequence` instance (`String`, `StringBuilder`, `StringBuffer`, etc.):

```
CharSequence cs = "John";
getPrefix("Name");

cs = new StringBuilder("James");
getPrefix(cs);
```

Normal applications hardly make use of the `CharSequence` interface, but that's applicable in some cases (libraries in particular).

It doesn't make much sense to write:

```
CharSequence sub = stringObject.subSequence(0, 1);
```

Because one normally expects a `String`-typed substring, but a framework may prefer to use `CharSequence` in its API, instead of `String`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there really no benefit to using subSequence()?

```
-> I do not see any real benefit of that method.
```

> If so, why has it been introduced?

```
-> As per Java API note "This method is defined so that the  String class can implement the  CharSequence interface". As `CharSequence` has the abstract method CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end);
```